Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws] in wildfly27
i get the following error when running wildfly:
17:22:01,520 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader](ServerService Thread Pool -- 51) Context initialization failed:org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws
Offending resource: ServletContext resource /WEB-INF/cxf-beans.xml at org.springframework.spring//org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:72)
I've tried the following:

Put the jaxws.xsd under WEB-INF/ and set this value in cxf-beans.xml
Put cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-4.0.4.jar in module in modules.xml
Put cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-4.0.4.jar as part of wildfly (under org.apache.cxf.impl)
my WEB-INF/cxf-beans.xml already contains   xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">

What could be the issue??
